# C++ BST insert function, it uses wrong path

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am making a insertion function in a BST. This is my code. I compiled and tried some insertions (25, 10, 8 sequently). I expected 25/10/8 as a result but what I got as a result is 25/10,8 . I have been seeing this a day but I cannot find what I got wrong. Does anyone know any problem?

```
Node* BST::insert(Node *root, elem val) {
Node *pNewNode = new Node(val);
if(root == NULL) {
    root = pNewNode;
    cout<<"1"<<endl;
    return root;
} else {
    pCursor1 = root;
    while(1) {
        if(val <= pCursor1->val) {
            if(pCursor1->pLeft == NULL) {
                pCursor1->pLeft = pNewNode;
                cout<<"2"<<endl;
                return root;
            } else { pCursor1 = pCursor1->pLeft; cout<<"3"<<endl; }
        } else {
            if(pCursor1->pRight == NULL) {
                pCursor1->pRight = pNewNode;
                cout<<"4"<<endl;
                return root;
            } else { pCursor1 = pCursor1->pRight; cout<<"5"<<endl;}
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So the error is just in the display? `25/10/8` vs `25/10,8`

Comment: BST insertion should make a result like this 25/10/8

Comment: but mine is making 25/10,8

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, as it is unclear as what you're trying to achieve.  What do you mean by `25/10,8` as opposed to `25/10/8`?  What is the significance of the `,`?

Comment: 25/10,8 means root->val:25 root->left->val10 root->right->val:8 and 25/10/8 means root->val: 25 root->left->val:10 root->left->left->val:8. I notated each of slash as a division line in level of trees. level1/level2(same level here)/level3

Comment: Have you considered stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Yeah but I don’t know why it isn’t working correctly. When i put 8, a new node has to go cout<<“3” section but some reason it goes cout<<4<< section.

Comment: If you step through your code you'll be able to see what happens. The first time you make a new root node, the second you add a node to the left, the 3rd time pLeft isn't null, so you set the cursor to the left node and the next iteration adds the new node to pCursor->left. Since that appears to be what you're looking for I'm not sure what the issue is. You might consider a complete example, since the code I had to add is almost certainly not the same as your code.